How can I create a formula that adjusts a cell range based on its relative position from a reference cell?
First time asking a question here. In cell J4 of an Excel tab, I have the string "C6:O43." This string is meant to refer to a range of cells on another tab. I plan to use this string as a paste range in a VBA macro. Cell J4 is the upper-leftmost cell in a range of cells that is 8 rows long and 34 columns wide. In the remaining cells, I wish to create a formula that adjusts "C6:O43" by shifting the column letters by a multiple of 16 and the row numbers by a multiple of 44, based on the relative position of each cell from the reference cell, J4.
For example, the first three rows and columns of this array should look like this:










C6:O43
S6:AE43
AI6:AU43


C50:O87
S50:AE87
AI50:AU87


C94:O131
S94:AE131
AI94:AU131



So far, I have figured out how to isolate each part of a range. So, for example, I have already written formulas that can break "C6:O43" into C, 6, O, and 43. And I know how to determine a cell's position relative to J4.
=COLUMN()-COLUMN($J$4)
=ROW()-ROW($J$4)

Apart from that, I'm a bit lost and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

if you will reference this in VBA, why don't you do the full calculation for the reference in VBA as well. Cells(x,y) can work wonders. X and Y can be incremented.

Use ADDRESS and some math:
=ADDRESS((ROW($A1)-1)*44+6,(COLUMN(A$1)-1)*16+3,4)&":"&ADDRESS((ROW($A1)-1)*44+43,(COLUMN(A$1)-1)*16+15,4)

Now as you drag it over and down the ROW() and COULUM() will iterate and the math will return the correct numbers to ADDRESS.


If you want to use the output of these worksheet functions in VBA to address ranges, then I suggest you may want to do the calculations in VBA as well.
Cells(row,column) can be used to express a single cell.
Use Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(5, 3)) to contstruct a range.
The numbers supplied for the parameters row and column can be variables that are easily incremented.
a = a + 16
b = b + 34

combined with cells(a,b)

a non-dynamical solution using a formula could be:
={"C","S","AI"}&{6;50;94}&{":O",":AE",":AU"}&{43;87;131}
And using Office 365 you may use this dynamical solution:
=LET(INCREMENT,
     LAMBDA(
            RowsCreate,
            RowStartNo,
            RowIncr,
            ColumnsCreate,
            ColumnStartNo,
            ColumnIncr,
     LET(i,INT((SEQUENCE(,ColumnsCreate,ColumnStartNo,ColumnIncr)-{27;1;0})/{676;26;1}),
         BYCOL(IF(i>0,CHAR(MOD(i-1,26)+65),""),
        LAMBDA(b,
               CONCAT(b)))
         &SEQUENCE(RowsCreate,,RowStartNo,RowIncr))),
INCREMENT(3,6,44,3,3,16)&":"&INCREMENT(3,43,44,3,15,16))

For this solution I created a LAMBDA called INCREMENT, which has arguments where you need to declare:

RowsCreate - the number of rows your result should be.
RowStartNo - the start number of the first row of your result.
RowIncr - the number of rows to increment per row.

And the same logic, but for columns instead of rows for ColumnsCreate, ColumnStartNo, ColumnIncr


Bit of overkill, since VBA is easier, but fun challenge.

As others have said, if you're going to use these references in VBA then you might as well do the calculations there as well.
For instance, to determine the range referred to in J4, but on a different sheet:
set rng = sheets(2).range(sheets(1).range("J4").text)
To determine the range shifted by multiples of 16 and 44:
set rng=rng.offset(n*44,m*16)
